# Selenium Fitnesse Bridge: How do I store and echo a variable?

Tags: selenium, fixtures, fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

I'm using the [Selenium Fitnesse Bridge Fixture](http://www.michaelshimer.com/demo/demo.html) in order to write tests in Fitnesse for Selenium. It's great because it covers **ALL** the functions that Selenium has. However, the problem I'm running into is storing variables like I would in Selenium IDE.

```
| !- fixtures.SeleniumFixture -!|
| setup | http://www.google.com/ | *chrome /usr/lib/firefox-3.0.5/firefox |
| open | http://www.google.com/ |  |
| storeLocation | here | |
| echo | ${here} |  |
```

Something as simple as this should work just fine, but when I save the test I get an error, undefined variable.

```
| storeLocation | here |  |
| echo | undefined variable: here |  |
```

This just doesn't make sense. I'm defining the variable the line before I echo it. When I run the test, I get:

```
| storeLocation | here |  |
| echo | undefined variable: here | undefined variable: here |
```

The author is doing the same sort of thing with [his tests](http://www.michaelshimer.com/demo/alltests.html). Why won't this work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Fitnesse is getting confused. It thinks that you are not defining a variable.

```
!define variable {variable}
| echo | ${variable} |  |
```

The way to get around Fitnesse's confusion is to escape the variable name by surrounding it with !- -!.

```
| storeLocation | here | |
| echo | ${!-here-!} |  |
```

This will now echo the desired response.

```
| !- fixtures.SeleniumFixture -!|
| setup | http://www.google.com/ | *chrome /usr/lib/firefox-3.0.5/firefox |
| open | http://www.google.com/ |  |
| storeLocation | here | |
| echo | ${here} | http://www.google.com |
```